# Where can I find the bonus chests from the DLC?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I purchased the DLC (expansion pass) for The Legend of Zelda - Breath of the Wild and I was told that there would be additional chests on the plateau.

Where do I find these chests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one chest located near three of the shrines on the Great Plateau. The chests all have 'EX' on them, so it's easy to tell if they are the DLC ones.

The first chest is located right next to the Oman Au (Magnesis) shrine, on the left facing the entrance. Contains 1 Ruby.

The second chest is located on a wall near Ja Baij (Remote Bomb) shrine. Exit the shrine and look up and to the left. Contains the Nintendo Switch Shirt.

The third chest is located near Keh Namut (Cyronis) shrine. Fast Travel to the shrine, turn around, and go behind the shrine. It should be on a wall to the right. Contains 5 bomb arrows.